# Spark partitioning within transformation chains with explicit and default partitioners

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning

Suppose I start with partitioning my data on the outset:

i.e:

```
val rdd: RDD[Int, String] = ...;
val data = rdd.partitionBy(new RangePartitioner(8, rdd)).persist()
```

and then lets say I did:

```
val groupedData = data.groupByKey() // what is the partitioner here?
```

Typically, groupByKey has default partitioning logic of using a HashPartitioner - in this case, will it keep using the parent partitioner, or will it re-partition the data according to the default?

I looked at [Partitioner#defaultPartitioner](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala), and that does seem to be the case (that you use the default partitioning logic only if an explicit partitioner hasn't been specified), but I thought I'd do a sanity check.

As an additional question, barring the key-changing transformation like #map, #flatMap etc. For all the key-preserving transformations, do they all hold-onto and propagate the explicitly defined partitioner? What about if I never partition the data, do they propagate the prior level's defaults?

i.e.:

```
rdd.groupByKey() // hash-partitioner by default
.mapValues(_.head)
.sortByKey //range-partitioner by default, but does it use the hash-partitioner from before?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case partitioner will be preserved. It is easy to check

```
for {
  p1 <- groupedData.partitioner
  p2 <- data.partitioner
} yield p1 == p2

// Some(true)
```

In the second case partitioner is [inherent part of the transformation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/OrderedRDDFunctions.scala#L62) so the `HashPartitioner` will be discarded:

```
val grouped = rdd.groupByKey

for {
  p1 <- grouped.partitioner
  p2 <- grouped.sortByKey().partitioner
} yield p1 == p2

// Some(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the .partitioner function. I didn't realized that existed. Here's what I don't get. The function call to .sortByKey() creates internally a RangePartitioner for use with the transformation. This is passed along to the ShuffledRDD. This makes me think that if I do grouped = rdd.partitionBy(HashKeyPartitioner).persist() and then grouped.sortByKey() the partitioner in grouped.sortByKey() should not be the same as the HashKeyPartitioner provided to partitionBy. Is there a reason for this behavior? and any idea where to find it in the code?